# numpy dot behaving strange

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to `numpy`. So I have a very simple matrix factor multiplication, something as follows:

```
vecT = np.dot(matDT, vecGradU)
```

Now depending on the input, sometimes this results in a column vector

```
print("matDT -> ", matDT.shape)
print("vecGradU -> ", vecGradU.shape)
print("vecT -> ", vecT.shape)
```

These are the results for one input:

```
matDT ->  (4, 4)
vecGradU ->  (4,)
vecT ->  (4,)
```

for another input

```
matDT ->  (9, 9)
vecGradU ->  (9,)
vecT ->  (1, 9)
```

Why would the `dot` function behave differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the types of the arguments in the two cases.  I suspect that in the case where the result has shape (1, 9), `matDT` is a numpy `matrix`, not a numpy `ndarray`.

For example,

```
In [52]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [53]: m = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [54]: b = np.array([4,5])

In [55]: np.dot(a, b)
Out[55]: array([14, 32])

In [56]: np.dot(a, b).shape
Out[56]: (2,)

In [57]: np.dot(m, b)
Out[57]: matrix([[14, 32]])

In [58]: np.dot(m, b).shape
Out[58]: (1, 2)
```

Comment: This is the issue! You were right, in one case it was a type `<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>` and in the other it was `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. They got messed up because in the case that was wrong I was using `np.matlib.eye(n)` to create an identity matrix instead of `np.eye(n)`. Thanks!